# How to Insert an entry to MySQL DB from HTML Form

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a form with some field in my page. For example - auth.php. The data in fields of this form recieved by calling some php function, that gives this data from MySQL DB. The code:

```
<?php
    include 'functions.php';
    $result=array();
    $result = GetEntries();
    $json = json_encode($result);
?>
```

The data inserting in fields by this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nextFunc(){
        var name2 = <?php echo $json;?>;
        document.getElementById("rname").value = name2[currententry]['Name'];
    }
</script>
```

But how to realize mechanism of insertion some entry to my MySQL DB. For example, user pressed the ADD button on my Form, fill the field "Name" by his own data and press SAVE button - i want to save this user data directly in my MySQL DB.

Please help!

Comment: As a broad overview, you would post that data to the server (maybe a standard form post, maybe an AJAX request, etc.) and the server-side code would read the posted values and perform the INSERT operation on the database.  There are many tutorials which cover these concepts and many examples available.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I found this example - https://gordoncluster.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-jquery-ajax-php/. Yes, it works, but that example uses POST method, but what if I don't want to use standart form and I want to use own images in button capacity. 

So - I want to know how i can realize it by using :

<img src="2.jpg" name="Ins" id="ains" onClick="AddEntry()"> construction

Comment: What does "own images in button capacity" even mean?  Whatever data you want to insert into the database needs to be posted to the server.  Generally your options are a form post or AJAX.  Either way, what you're asking is too broad for Stack Overflow.  We can help with specific problems, but introductory tutorials are already plentiful on the internet.

Comment: @AntonRomanov No, avoid that tutorial at all costs. It uses the obsolete `mysql_query` and doesn't employ prepared statements to ensure the data is encoded correctly. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you'll need to follow a few steps:

1. create the html form

### form.html

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <label>
    Name <input type="text" name="name" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

2. create submit page

### submit.php

```
<?php

$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);

// connect to database
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'db_username', 'db_password', 'db_name');
if ($con->connect_errno) {
   printf("Failed to connect to mysql: %s", $con->connect_error);
}

// prepare the query
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO my_table SET name = '%s'", $name);

// insert into database
$query = $con->query($sql) or die($con->error);
// view ID of last inserted row in the database
print_r('Last inserted ID: '.$con->insert_id);
```

Now you should be able to have your data in database.

Please have a look at this example on how to connect to database http://docs.kisphp.net/database-connect/

Instead of mysqli you may/should use PDO.

#### P.S.

In your code:

```
include 'functions.php';
$result=array();              // this line should not be here
$result = GetEntries();       // is overwritten by this one
$json = json_encode($result);
```

Is always a good practice to follow some principles:

- function names starts with lowercase
- class names starts with uppercase
- do not use `?>` in php files that contains only PHP code
- indentation of all code is not necessary.

and so on.
you may find here more details http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

#### P.P.S.

This is basic usage. Once you understand the principle you can extend it to ajax. Create an ajax function that will submit the form data to `submit.php` file.